# How to align string after variable text length

Tags: python

I'm looking to add padding after text to align a column of strings:

example output:

```
a:        ***
aa:       ***
aaa:      ***
```

I've tried adding adding a left and right adjust to format, but it seems to make the adjustment after the `:`

```py
s = 'a: {:>10}\n' \
    'aa: {:>10}\n' \
    'aaa: {:>10}'
print(s.format('***', '***', '***'))
```

which outputs

```
a:        ***
aa:        ***
aaa:        ***
```

Is there any way to account for the variable length of the `a, aa, aaa`

Comment: You can use the string methods `ljust` and `rjust`.

Comment: You should add formatting to first column as well. Second column starts right after first column and if first column values have variable length then second column starts in different positions causing non-alignement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For python 3.x, use f-string syntax:

```
print(f'{"a:":<5}{"***":>10}\n' \
    f'{"aa:":<5}{"***":>10}\n' \
    f'{"aaa:":<5}{"***":>10}'
    )
```

For python 2.x, use "str.ljust(width)" and string concatenation(str+str):

```
s = 'a:'.ljust(5)+'{:>10}\n'+\
    'aa:'.ljust(5)+'{:>10}\n'+\
    'aaa:'.ljust(5)+'{:>10}'
print(s.format('***','***','***'))
```

Both will give you the expected result:

```
a:          ***
aa:         ***
aaa:        ***
```